# How to add color to texture in node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm new quite new making textures from nodes and I don't know how to add color to my current texture, Here's what I mean.

Here's the node tree.[image: 1]

And I want the white parts to be another color.[image: 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a *Color > MixRGB* node in *Multiply* mode just before your shader, and put the factor at 1 (here I've used an *Image Texture* for the wool texture but it would be exactly the same if yours is procedural):

[image]

Comment: Ah I see So basically right before the output.

Comment: right before the shader node (Principled BSDF or Diffuse or Mix Shader...), you always need a shader node before the Material Output itself